# How to get ComboBox from TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, tableview, javafx-8

I have TableView instance and some columns contains ComboBoxes.

```
private TableView<ScheduleLecture> tableSchedule;
private TableColumn<ScheduleLecture, DayOfWeek> colDay;

private void initialize() {
colDay.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("day"));
colDay.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(DayOfWeek.values()));
```

I need to expand ComboBox of TableCell when is focused.

```
public void onTableMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    if (tableSchedule.getEditingCell() == null) {
        int row = tableSchedule.getSelectionModel().getFocusedIndex();
        ObservableList<TablePosition> selectedCells = tableSchedule.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
        if(selectedCells.size() == 0){
            return;
        }
        TableColumn col = selectedCells.get(0).getTableColumn();
        tableSchedule.edit(row, col);
        Object cellData = col.getCellData(0);
        if(cellData instanceof Enum){
            if(cellData instanceof DayOfWeek){
                //comboBox.show(); for cell [row, col.index]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How me do it??

Answer (score -1):

If you need to get graphic from cells look this link 
[This page lists the demo code for method getGraphic from TableCell in package javafx.scene.control.](http://book2s.com/java/api/javafx/scene/control/tablecell/getgraphic-0.html)